# Copying text from PeopleSoft to Windows 7 Professional clipboard

Tags: windows-7, windows, clipboard

When I had Windows XP, I had to select the silver windows theme in order to copy text to the clipboard in our PeopleSoft application.  Now, I have Windows 7 Professional with Service Pack 1.

What do I need to do in order to be able to copy text from PeopleSoft to the clipboard?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Your question title is not clear and the body is not much better. What exactly is being asked? What does a Windows theme have to do with copying to the clipboard?

Comment: How old is this version of Peoplesoft?  Given that this is a corporate piece of software have you reported this to your IT department to seek a fix through your supplier?